# newcommand for hvfloat

Tags: macros

Using the hvfloat package:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[showframe,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{Test chapter}

\hvFloat[%
floatPos=htb,%
capVPos=c,%
rotAngle=90,
objectPos=c]{figure}{\includegraphics[width=353pt,height=290pt]{image}}%
[Commercial crude oil inventories, SPX excess returns, S\&P GCSI excess return time series]{Commercial crude oil inventories calculated as the logarithm of the current value divided by the mean of same weekly values over the past 5 years, Log excess returns on the S\&P Goldman Sachs Commodity Index,  Log excess returns on the S\&P 500 index.}{fig:test}

\end{document}
```

can I in any way write a function that automatically rotate the "object" (rotAngle), depending on if the figure is on a even or odd page:

Have tried:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\currentside}{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{270}{90}}

rotAngle = \currentside
```

But can't get i to work.. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: the command you created refers to the value of `rotAngle`, right? (because the value you're using for `objectPos` is `c`)

Comment: @henrique: true. any suggestion?

Comment: i'm working on it :)

Answer (score 2):

Define a special key which then takes the label of the image into account with `\pageref{..}`

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[showframe,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\makeatletter
\define@key{hvSet}{RotAngle}[]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\def\hvSet@rotAngle{90}\else
    \ifodd\pageref{#1}\def\hvSet@rotAngle{90}\else\def\hvSet@rotAngle{270}\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{Test chapter}

\hvFloat[%
floatPos=htb,%
capVPos=c,%
RotAngle=fig:test,
objectPos=c]{figure}{\includegraphics[width=300pt,height=290pt]{image}}%
[Commercial crude oil inventories, SPX excess returns, S\&P GCSI excess return time series]{Commercial crude oil inventories calculated as the logarithm of the current value divided by the mean of same weekly values over the past 5 years, Log excess returns on the S\&P Goldman Sachs Commodity Index,  Log excess returns on the S\&P 500 index.}{fig:test}

\clearpage

\hvFloat[
floatPos=htb,
capVPos=c,
RotAngle=fig:testA,
objectPos=c]{figure}{\includegraphics[width=353pt,height=290pt]{image}}%
[Commercial crude oil inventories, SPX excess returns, S\&P GCSI excess return time series]{Commercial crude oil inventories calculated as the logarithm of the current value divided by the mean of same weekly values over the past 5 years, Log excess returns on the S\&P Goldman Sachs Commodity Index,  Log excess returns on the S\&P 500 index.}{fig:testA}

\clearpage

\hvFloat[
floatPos=htb,
capVPos=c,
RotAngle=,
objectPos=c]{figure}{\includegraphics[width=353pt,height=290pt]{image}}%
[Commercial crude oil inventories, SPX excess returns, S\&P GCSI excess return time series]{Commercial crude oil inventories calculated as the logarithm of the current value divided by the mean of same weekly values over the past 5 years, Log excess returns on the S\&P Goldman Sachs Commodity Index,  Log excess returns on the S\&P 500 index.}{fig:testB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Herbert: When I try to add more firgure, i get: Appendix A.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.19 ...graphics[width=300pt,height=290pt]{image}}
                                                  %
?    Any idea why?

Comment: @latexmp: I modified the example to allow `RotAngle=` with an empty argument. In this case `rotAngle=90` is assumed. However, you need for every image a label, otherwise `\pageref` won't work. We need this, because `\ifodd\thepage` didn't work in all cases.

Comment: @Herbert: thnks! Just one more question... Is it hard to make the horizontalplacement (objectPos) to left (l) on even pages and right (r) on odd pages?

Comment: @latexmp: no, you can do it in the same way as for `RotAngle`. Define a new key `ObjectPos` which uses the same `\pageref{#1}` for setting `objectPos`. It is also possible to set this inside the `RotAngle` key itself.

Comment: @Herbert: ok. If i try to make the image wider and higher, it sometimes jump to a new page, but do not rotate the right way. Also i struggle to get a figure at the same page as the heading if i try to make it wider. What i like is to use the full height of the page (width of figure) and adjust the width (height of the figure) so it fit the page, including the caption...

Comment: @latexmp: the images are placed as default floating objects with all restrictions. You can also use the nonfloat option.

Comment: @Herbert: instead of `\pageref` one might use `\getpagerefnumber` (loading **refcount**) that avoids problems when the label is new.

Comment: @latexmp: If I find some time, I'll create optional arguments for inenr/outer margins.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a command with the `\ifthenelse` setting the whole `\hvFloat` stuff, insted of just an argument for one of its options. Something like:

```
 \hvFloat[floatPos=htb,capVPos=c,rotAngle=90,objectPos=c]% options
     {figure}%     float type
     {\includegraphics[width=353pt,height=290pt]{#1}}%     object: Argument #1 Stands for the image location
     [#2]%     Arg #2 = short caption
     {#3}%     Arg #3 = long caption
     {#4}%     Arg #4 = label
 }{    
 \hvFloat[floatPos=htb,capVPos=c,rotAngle=270,objectPos=c]%     options
     {figure}%     float type
     {\includegraphics[width=353pt,height=290pt]{#1}}%     object: Argument #1 Stands for the image location
     [#2]%     Arg #2 = short caption
     {#3}%     Arg #3 = long caption
     {#4}%     Arg #4 = label
 }
}
```

(But that didn't work here...)

I managed to do something like *without* the `hvfloat` package, but I don't know if it suits your needs:

```
\newcommand{\currentside}[2]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{%
  \begin{figure}[htb]%
   \includegraphics[height=\textwidth,angle=270]{#1}%
   \caption{#2}%
  \end{figure}%
 }{%
  \begin{figure}[htb]%
   \includegraphics[height=\textwidth,angle=90]{#1}%
   \caption{#2}%
  \end{figure}%
 }%
}
```